# What is the value of the partition function of CFT on a compact conformal manifold?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-geometry, conformal-field-theory

Is the value of the partition function of a 2d CFT on a compact conformal manifold well defined? Or is there some kind of "anomaly" that makes it dependent on a bulk or some other kind of further structure (as for some $2+1$-dimensional TQFTs)?

If yes, are there formulas that compute it given some topology-dependent parametrisation (elements of the corresponding conformal moduli space), and some data connected to the CFT? Like, for example, depending on the central charge $c$ and on the ratio $R/r$ or a $R\times r$ torus?

This seems to be the one of the most straight-forward questions about CFT, but somehow I'm having a hard time finding anything, mostly because introductions usually focus on CFT on the plane or cylinder.

Comment: Is this a question about 2d CFT?  There's a huge literature on this, which could be caricatured as "the partition function is a section of a line bundle on the moduli stack of curves".   In d > 2, the unnormalized partition function is going to be infinite.

Comment: thanks, yes, I mean 2d, will edit. The partition function is a real number for every point in moduli space, so isn't it always trivially a section of the trivial line bundle? Are there references that contain plain numbers for concrete CFTs and conformal manifolds?

Comment: The partition function is a section of the trivial bundle on the space of Riemannian structures, but if the central charge $c$ is non-zero it descends to a section of a non-trivial line bundle on the space of complex structures.  I should probably try to write this up as an answer, but don't have time now.

Comment: Thanks, I can wait ;) I'm a bit confused: Don't all non-trivial CFTs have a non-zero central charge? So are you saying the partition function on a fixed conformal manifold is not a well defined quantity in CFT?

Comment: I think unless when your VOA is holomorphic (say moonshine), the (chiral) partition function is not well defined.

Comment: Meanwhile I found that CFT does in fact have a "conformal anomaly" (unless $c=0$), meaning that the partition function is only defined up to a phase. If I understand correctly, one could say the partition function actually depends on the full metric (not only the conformal structure), but changes under local rescalings in a fixed way (by the Liouville cocycle).